# Using iron-router with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor, iron-router

I've installed iron-router for my Meteor project which is using jQM for the UI, but when I set-up a simple route, I cannot get my jQM page to show.

My router.js is as follows:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('splash', {path: '/'});
});
```

My layout.html is as follows:

```
<template name="layout">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="q" id="splashPage">
        <div data-role="content">
            {{>yield}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And my splash.html is as follows:

```
<template name="splash">
    <div class="login">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hub logo">
    </div>
</template>
```

As I understand iron-router the `{{>yield}}` should just put in whatever template you've defined in the router.js, in this case `splash` for the root URI. What's happening is that I do see that in the resulting HTML but there's a separate div that appears to be interfering with jQM.  Any ideas how to get the two divs to reconcile?

Where's the resulting HTML:

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a">
    <div data-role="page" data-url="/" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" style="min-height: 324px;">
    </div>
    <div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">
        <span class="ui-icon-loading"></span>
        <h1>loading</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="q" id="splashPage">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="login">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Approval Hub logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's `jQuery UI's` doing, I do think it needs those `divs` it doesn't seem like a `Meteor` issue, with that said, where is the jQuery UI call happening in your `js-code` ?

Comment: Yeah, it makes me suspect whether they can live together.  The first DIV I think is coming from jQM. The last DIV (the one iron-router is generating) is the one I want.

Comment: Similarly asked question in Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/NpExjw1CLQQ